# Get a matched values from datatables

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get matched value from dataTable my code is

```
 DataTable match = MnDt.AsEnumerable()
                       .Intersect(dataTable.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default)
                       .CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

MnDt table contains

```
1   1236    1   0   0   0
3   1236    1   0   0   0
3   5       1   0   55  40
```

and datatable contains

```
3   5   1   0   55  40
```

I want to get output as

```
3   5   1   0   55  40
```

from MnDt;

Please help me to resolve..

Comment: What is the problem you are having with your code?

Comment: getting error  : The source contains no DataRows.

Comment: you question says non matched and title and code reflects matching rows to be found.

Comment: Do you want matching values or non matching values?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DataTable match = MnDt.AsEnumerable().Where((x) =>
{
    bool second_table_contains_this_row = false;

    foreach (var second_table_row in dataTable.AsEnumerable())
    {
       second_table_contains_this_row = MethodForCompareTwoRows(x, second_table_row);
       if (second_table_contains_this_row)
           break;
    }

    return second_table_contains_this_row;
}.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

You can add whatever logic you want, inluding custom filtering inside "where" implementation. Always search agile solutions, avoid using "ready-to-run" code.